Driver for WCN785x Wi-Fi 7(802.11be) 320MHz 2x2, Qualcomm Technologies. Not working. qmi failed to load regdb bin
ISSUE: Network Settings do not show wifi but ubuntu lists correct hw.
Im running the following with a MSI Z790 ace max motherboard.
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS                
          Kernel: Linux 6.8.0-49-generic
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
  Hardware Model: MS-7D86
Firmware Version: A.43
   Firmware Date: Wed 2024-06-19
    Firmware Age: 5month 1w 6d

The exact network manager I'm using is:
*-network
       description: Network controller
       product: WCN785x Wi-Fi 7(802.11be) 320MHz 2x2 [FastConnect 7800]
       vendor: Qualcomm Technologies, Inc
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ath12k_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:239 memory:81200000-813fffff

When I inspect dmesg for ath12k I get the following:
[    5.703227] ath12k_pci 0000:07:00.0: BAR 0 [mem 0x81200000-0x813fffff 64bit]: assigned
[    5.703244] ath12k_pci 0000:07:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.703393] ath12k_pci 0000:07:00.0: MSI vectors: 16
[    5.703397] ath12k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Hardware name: wcn7850 hw2.0
[    6.266352] ath12k_pci 0000:07:00.0: chip_id 0x2 chip_family 0x4 board_id 0xff soc_id 0x40170200
[    6.266364] ath12k_pci 0000:07:00.0: fw_version 0x100301e1 fw_build_timestamp 2023-12-06 04:05 fw_build_id QC_IMAGE_VERSION_STRING=WLAN.HMT.1.0.c5-00481-QCAHMTSWPL_V1.0_V2.0_SILICONZ-3
[    6.266398] ath12k_pci 0000:07:00.0: qmi failed to load regdb bin:
[    6.266399] ath12k_pci 0000:07:00.0: qmi failed to load regdb file:-2

I found this:
https://lore.kernel.org/all/87ttmlrc8l.fsf@kernel.org/T/
Which states that
regdb.bin is for developer testing, end users shouldn't use that file.
Can you try ath.git master branch:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/kvalo/ath.git/log/
We have some patches in the pipeline which didn't sadly make it to v6.8.
However link doesnt work, I tried downloading latest ath12k-firmware but it also did not work. (following: https://wireless.docs.kernel.org/en/latest/en/users/drivers/ath12k/installation.html)
If I update to a newer kernel version, my GPU drivers stop working.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

You could enable proposed repos in Ubuntu 24.04 and install linux-image-6.11.0-12-generic

Aren't this versions still not stable? If I only need a specific driver why do I need to update the whole kernel?

The driver is in the kernel, you will likely be upgraded to the 6.11 kernel in January

Ok, could you guide me on how to upgrade the kernel? I installed the linux image and rebooted however I get an error at boot time that reads "bad shim signature", "error: you need to load the kernel first"

Might also need to sudo apt install linux-headers-6.11.0-12-generic linux-modules-extra-6.11.0-12-generic

Thanks to @Jeremy31
Upgraded to the latest signed linux image worked. The shim signature error I was getting was because system was booting into a newer kernel I previously downloaded.
just install 6.11.0-12-generic.
However by updating the kernel, the GPU drivers stopped working. So this is not a solution for my case

Please click the gray check next to your answer to mark it as accepted.
